# Failure in query for google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, query-string, google-sheets-formula

I'm making a query for the Google spreadsheet and it's giving me an error in the last part of it. The query works with 3 data that are inserted by validation in boxes B1, D1 and B2

This is what I have:

`= if (AND (B1 = 0; B2 = 0; D1 = 0); IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista! A6: S1000"); if (AND (B1> 1; B2> 1; D1 = 0); query (IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista! A6: S1000"); "select * where Col6 = '" & B1 & "' and Col8 = '" & B2 & "'"); query (IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista! A6: S1000 ");" select * where Col6 IN ('"& B1 &"', '"& D1 &"') and Col8 = '"& B2 &"' ")))`

This is the part that fails me:

`query (IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista! A6: S1000"); "select * where Col6 IN ('" & B1 & "', '" & D1 & "') and Col8 = '" & B2 & "'")))`

The error it gives me is:

Unable to parse the string of the query for the QUERY function, parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "" Col6 "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" .. .

Modify the line to solve the previous error "I think"

`query (IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista! A6: S1000"); "select * where Col6 IN" ("'" & B1 & "', '" & D1 & "'") "and Col8 = '" & B2 & "'") ))`

And I get the error:

Formula analysis error.

This last part, should select the data that have the category B1 and D1 and filter them through the B2 zone.

For example B1 and D1 are police ranks and B2 where they are destined

Comment: Again with the missing ampersands, I believe. :)

Comment: @c0de missing ampersands were?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'IN' operator in google sheets query function. See if this works

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista!A6:S1000"); "select * where (Col6 = '"&B1&"' or Col6 = '"&D1&"') and Col8 = '"&B2&"'")
```

Comment: I noticed you accepted the answer. Does that mean it works now? If not, can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, think it's actually that you've moved the parentheses out of the string. Try:

`=query (IMPORTRANGE ("LINK"; "Llista! A6: S1000");"select * where Col6 IN ('" & B1 & "', '" & D1 & "') and Col8 = '" & B2 & "'")))`

**EDIT**
Also:
I'm not as familiar with query, but I know that Google's version is slightly limited. You may be unable to use 'IN'. I can't find any reference to it in the official documentation. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: Is that exactly what you have? The parentheses have been moved and some quotation marks removed. Please update with any new error message.

Comment: Unable to parse the query string for In the QUERY function, parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "<ID>" Col6 "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "( "...

Comment: I'm not as familiar with query, but I know that Google's version is slightly limited. You may be unable to use 'IN'. I can't find any reference to it in the official documentation. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage